# Firefox [npapi] plugin development - firefox freeze when calling a method

Tags: firefox, plugins, freeze, npapi

I'm trying to learn how to write a Firefox plugin.
I downloaded the npruntime example from Mozilla compiled it and ran it.
Getting properties from the plugin worked well but when I tried to
call a method, Firefox freezed.
I thought maybe something is wrong with the example, so I wrote my own basic scriptable plugin that has one property and one method which returns a string.
The property worked well, but calling the method caused Firefox to freeze, again.

Am I missing something?
I tried debugging the plugin and everything seems fine. All the right
functions are called and the value is returned properly.If I try to stop the process while Firefox hangs, I get stopped at a Windows DLL, not in my code and not in Firefox code.

If anyone can point me to the right direction...

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I hope that you've got it solved. If this is not the case, I've just discovered that the example (I assume that was the damned "npruntime sample") was flawed.

In returning a string, the example used the function `strdup` to allocate a string passed with a NP_something method.
Fact is that NPAPI takes care of the allocated string from that point on and, when tries to destroy it, it cannot since `strdup` uses `malloc` and not `NPN_MemAlloc`.

The solution is to NEVER use `malloc` or new for objects that we pass to NPAPI functions.
In the npruntime sample the error is at line 452:

```
STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT(strdup("foo return val"), *result);
```

and line 466:

```
STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT(strdup("default method return val"), *result);
```

I've corrected it with this code:

```
char* src = "foo return val";
char* out = (char *)NPN_MemAlloc(strlen(src) + 1);
strcpy(out, src);
STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT(out, *result);
```

and it worked.
But one would think that such a flaw in a sample should be corrected by mozilla SDK maintainers.

Comment: Good find! Could you please find a bug -- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Plug-ins and if people don't react in a couple of weeks, try to find the right people to look at it (e.g. by asking around in irc.mozilla.org/developers)?

Comment: Hey, thanks!  One of our developers has filed a bug and put up a patch with your fix in it.  If you'd like to get named credit, drop in the bug and state your name.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530138

Answer (score 0):

I developed npruntime for every browser.
It worked well in every browser, but firefox got freezing only in Windows 7.

I solved the problem editing the firefox config "dom.ipc.plugins.enabled" to false.
I don't know it will work, but it deserves to try.